# Searching for string in multiple zip archives

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

*Here's what I have;*

On a windows-based web server there are roughly 1,000 zip files, each with dozens of log files inside. I already have a script that goes through each archive and deletes all but one specific file type (in an attempt to save diskspace and delete things I don't need). Then, the script unzips each archive to their own folder. And I know how to code the reverse of that to zip them back when I'm done.

*Here's what I need to figure out;*

Once I run the previously mentioned script (we call it garbageman because it cleans out the garbage in the zip files) I need to go through the remaining 5 or 6 files in each of the newly created unzipped folders, and look for a specific string in each file. If I find the string, I delete everything that is not that string, and save it to a file called "export.txt" in that folder. Then, I move to the next unzipped file, and so on. Once completed, I need re-zip everything back together into their own archives

Here's what I have for code so far. Any help is extremely appreciated.

```
    cd "C:\Program Files\7-Zip"
FOR %%c in (C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\LogQueue\*.*) DO 7z d %%c "-x!xstore*" -r


FOR /R "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\LogQueue" %%I in ("*.zip") do (
   "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -y -o"%%~dpnI" "%%~fI" 
 )

cd "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Desktop\LogQueue"

FOR /R "C:\Users\xxxxxx\Desktop\LogQueue" %%I in ("*.*") do (
  findstr "xxxxxxxx_eReceipt" %%~fI > %%~dpnI\export.txt
  pause
 )

for /d %%X in (*) do "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.zip" "%%X\"
```

Comment: I guess this is not really DOS but a command prompt under some Windows, is this right?

Comment: Do you need to delete each unzipped file after saving the string from it to `export.txt`? Also, delete dos tag from your question, and add Cmd related.

Comment: @sambul35 It would be nice if it did delete, but not the end of the world if it doesn't. The biggest thing I'm getting caught up in is writing a for statement that will go into each unzipped folder, search the string, and save the export.txt.

Comment: Is it okey to just extract the string instead of deleting all the lines around that string?

Comment: @Patrick see edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an edit:

This script should do what you want.

Only Change `sourcedir` and `mystring` variables.

`export.txt` will be inside a file called `Storage` in the root directory of the batch.

```
:ScriptA
@ECHO ON
MKDIR "%CD%\Storage"
MKDIR "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Outx"
GOTO :ScriptB

:ScriptB
::REM ONLY CHANGE
SET "sourcedir=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Test"
FOR /R "%sourcedir%\" %%a in (*.txt) do copy "%%a" "%CD%\Storage"
:ScriptC

:ScriptC
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "VARA=%CD%\Storage"
SET "VARB=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Out"
::REM ONLY CHANGE 
SET "mystring=PUT_STRING_HERE"
FOR %%a IN ("%VARA%\*.txt") DO FINDSTR "%mystring%" "%%a">nul&IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 FINDSTR "%mystring%" "%%a">"%VARB%\%%~nxa"
DEL /F "%CD%\Storage\*.txt"
GOTO :ScriptD

:ScriptD
@ECHO ON
COPY /B "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Outx\*.txt" "%CD%\Storage\export.txt"
RD /S /Q "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Outx"
goto :eof
```